# custom info window flutter web google map

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps, frontend, google-maps-flutter

I have created a flutter web google map using package google_map_flutter , ive seen couple of tutorials on how to include a custom info window using custom_info_window package, however this package is not flutter web supported. is there any alternative ways for flutter web to create a custom info model for google maps ?? my code is working perfectly but when i add the custom info window its not working and the error is platform not supported. following is my code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class Maps extends StatefulWidget {
  Maps({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Maps> createState() => _MapsState();
}

class _MapsState extends State<Maps> {
  late GoogleMapController mapscontroller;
  Set<Marker> _markers = Set();
  LatLng startLocation = LatLng(45.00076796865061, -93.27039033565887);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    addMarkers();
  }

  addMarkers() async {
    BitmapDescriptor markerbitmap = await BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
      ImageConfiguration(),
      'assets/images/favicon-48x48.png',
    );

    _markers.add(
      Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId("Sollocation"),
        position: LatLng(45.00076796865061, -93.27039033565887),
        icon: markerbitmap,
      ),
    );
    _markers.add(
      Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId('FaithLocation'),
        position: LatLng(45.001814008573774, -93.26947494050455),
        icon: markerbitmap,
      ),
    );
    _markers.add(
      Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId('BrettLocation'),
        position: LatLng(44.99971081652291, -93.26968972161463),
        icon: markerbitmap,
      ),
    );

    setState(() {
      //refresh UI
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GoogleMap(
        onMapCreated: (controller) {
          setState(() {
            mapscontroller = controller;
          });
        },
        markers: _markers,
        mapType: MapType.hybrid,
        initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(target: startLocation, zoom: 15));
  }
}
```